Alternative proof of Corollary 2.13 of Atiyah and Macdonald, on tensor products
In Atiyah and Macdonald, the following proposition (Corollary 2.13, p.25) about tensor products is given:

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are modules over a commutative ring, and $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(y_i)_{i\in I}$ are finite families of elements of $M$ and $N$ respectively. If $\sum_{i}x_i\otimes y_i=0$, then there are finitely generated submodules $M_0$ of $M$ and $N_0$ of $N$ such that $\sum _i x_i\otimes y_i=0$ as an element of $M_0\otimes N_0$.

Although the proof given there makes sense to me, it seems a little messy, and it also relies upon the explicit construction of the tensor product as a certain quotient of the free module on $M\times N$. Is there a way of proving the above proposition that just uses the universal property of tensor products?

As a left adjoint the tensor product preserves colimits. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the poset of finitely generated $M' \leq M$ such that $x_i \in M'$ for all $i$, so that $M = \bigcup_{M'\in \mathcal{P}} M'$. Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be defined similarly for $N$ and the $y_i$. Note that $\mathcal{P}$ has finite joins (sums of finitely generated submodules are still finitely generated) and so is directed. Directed colimits are calculated in algebraic categories like they are in the category of sets, and when all the maps involved are inclusions these are just unions. So $M = \operatorname{colim}_{M' \in \mathcal{P}} M'$ and $N = \operatorname{colim}_{N' \in \mathcal{Q}} N'$. Then $$M \otimes N = \operatorname{colim}\limits_{M' \in \mathcal{P}, N'\in \mathcal{Q}} M' \otimes N'.$$
This colimit is again over a directed poset and so calculated as it is in the category of sets. The nice thing about directed colimits is that any equality between elements in the system which holds after taking the colimit must also hold after going far enough out in the system. This idea may be familiar if you've ever worked with germs in the stalk of a sheaf, where a section $s$ on $U$ and $t$ on $V$ have the same germ iff there's some $W \subseteq U \cap V$ with $s|_U = t|_V$. This can be cast a special case of the fact that filtered (directed) colimits commute with finite limits, or it can be shown by an explicit construction of colimits in the category of sets.
